# Is this possible with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have strings that looks similar like this:

```
"size:34,35,36,36,37|color:blue,red,white"
```

is it possible to match all the colors in a preg_match(_all)?
so that i will get "blue", "red" and "white" in the output array?

the colors can be whatever, so i cant go (blue|red|white)

Comment: You should first match the `key:va,lu,es` pairs, and then explode the values on `,`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Explode on `|`
2. Explode on `:`
3. Explode on `,`
4. `???`
5. Profit!

### Code

IMHO using regular expressions like what's been suggested in the other answers is a much "uglier" solution than something simple like so:

```
$input = 'size:34,35,36,36,37|color:blue,red,white|undercoating:yes,no,maybe,42';

function get_option($name, $string) {
    $raw_opts = explode('|', $string);
    $pattern = sprintf('/^%s:/', $name);
    foreach( $raw_opts as $opt_str ) {
        if( preg_match($pattern, $opt_str) ) {
            $temp = explode(':', $opt_str);
            return $opts = explode(',', $temp[1]);
        }
    }
    return false; //no match
}

function get_all_options($string) {
    $options = array();
    $raw_opts = explode('|', $string);
    foreach( $raw_opts as $opt_str ) {
        $temp = explode(':', $opt_str);
        $options[$temp[0]] = explode(',', $temp[1]);
    }
    return $options;
}

print_r(get_option('undercoating', $input));
print_r(get_all_options($input));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => yes
    [1] => no
    [2] => maybe
    [3] => 42
)
Array
(
    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 34
            [1] => 35
            [2] => 36
            [3] => 36
            [4] => 37
        )

    [color] => Array
        (
            [0] => blue
            [1] => red
            [2] => white
        )

    [undercoating] => Array
        (
            [0] => yes
            [1] => no
            [2] => maybe
            [3] => 42
        )

)
```

Comment: yes, thats the code i have now, but just wanted to see if it was possible with just preg_match, because it looks so ugly and feels ugly too.

Comment: @KristianRafteseth The problem with regular expressions is that while they *seem* smart, they are profoundly stupid. It is a very complex way to accomplish only simple tasks. Added some code to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in a round about way with `preg_match_all()` but I'd recommend explode instead.

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z]+)(?:,|$)/', "size:34,35,36,36,37|color:blue,red,white", $a);
print_r($a[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible with [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
 /(?<=(^|\|)color:([^,|],)*)[^,|](?=\||,|$)/g
```

<sub>(for `preg_match_all`)</sub>

Your explode solution is obviously cleaner :-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with lookbehinds, but: `Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 25`

Comment: @Sammitch: All right, then PHP [doesn't support this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind). One would need to make assumptions on the input string like JamesC to solve it with regex…